# how to handle master slave in Jedis(java & redis)?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am curious about how to handle master slave connection in Jedis, similar we can achieve in JDBC using below code.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://master,slave/mysql", "user", "pwd");
```

So, that my application can connect to slave automatically in case of master failover.

Any suggestion regarding this will be help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### In short

There's not out-of-the-box support for higher order support of Redis Master/Slave.

### Explanation

Jedis supports Redis Standalone (with Slaves), Redis Sentinel and Redis Cluster operation modes. All three variants allow connecting Redis and use the master nodes to run commands.

If you want to use slaves for high-availability or to read from, that's something you need to implement on your own. Implementing an own pooling using slaves should do the job.

### Alternatives

You could use Redis Sentinel, to manage topology changes and master-failover (slaves get promoted to master) as Jedis supports Redis Sentinel.

[Redisson](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson) has a nice support for [Redis Master/Slave](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/2.-configuration#28-master-slave-mode). [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) also comes with support for Master/Slave. Both clients reconnect transparently (i.e. no more broken connections) and feature thread-safe connections (no more connection pooling).

Comment: which is better to use in production?